# How to find the rectangle that leaves the most free space on both sides of a smaller rectangle?

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to figure out an appropriate algorithm for my software but I can't find any relevant "textbook solution". I reduced the task to the following core problem.

Given choices of rectangular areas, I need to find the area that leaves the most space on all sides simultaneously of a smaller rectangle that is known to fit all of the areas.

Given:
Rectangle:
length=100, width=200

Areas (will be always preselected to be larger than the rectangle):

1. length=100, width=200
2. length=101, width=500
3. length=101, width=201
4. length=300, width=300 <- this is the best fit because it has the most of free space in both dimensions simultaneously, despite the fact that there are other options that have even more space, but in a single direction only
5. length=200, width=1000
6. length=1000, width=200

What should be the algorithm to find the 4) choice as the best fit?

Will be grateful for pseudocode or code in any C-like language or Python, or a pointer to some well-known algorithm.

The numbers were picked just for this test example. In real life, all the numbers could be any, as entered by users.

Comment: Seems you need to simply find the rectangles that the smaller rectangle will fit in, and then simply determine which of those rectangles has the most area (because this will mean it has the most area around the smaller rectangle, since the smaller one has a fixed area). Please take a shot at approaching it this way and produce some code. A hint is that you will need a loop over the rectangle candidates, and in loop you want to check if dimensions will allow smaller one, and you want to track one with largest area.

Comment: Your definition of most space is a little unprecise. You want min(length_diff, width_diff) as big as possible?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what "in both dimensions simultaneously" actually means.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire Unfortunately, that is not so simple. For example, 100x1000 will give a larger area than 300x300 but still 300x300 is a better fit because 100x1000 has no free space at all in length.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  Sorry, my English is not that good. I mean - it should find the candidates that are the most balanced in their spacing in both length and width. Imagine like you are trying to fit a detail onto a plane knowing that the plane should have as much space as possible on all sides, but also choose the option that has the space distributed the most evenly. That is - given a plane that has 10 length reserve and 100 width reserve and a plane that has 50 length reserve and 50 width reserve, you should take the second one.

Comment: @Anton hmm, there's something about it; min(length_diff, width_diff) formula might be what I'm looking for indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly this would be a solution (c++), didn't test it though:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    size_t x, y;
};

//returns first index which fits your condition
int alg(Rectangle a, Rectangle *others, size_t othersLen)
{
    unsigned int biggestIndex = 0;
    size_t biggest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < othersLen; i++)
    {
        size_t diffX = others[i].x - a.x;
        size_t diffY = others[i].y - a.y;
        size_t size = diffX > diffY ? diffY : diffX;
        if (size > biggest)
        {
            biggest = size;
            biggestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return biggestIndex;
}
```

Edit: Only works if the other rectangles are bigger than the given rectangle, because it doesn't do negative differences.